# Comma Separated Values in SQL with three tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables and a complicated SQL query to extract data from these tables. To put it in context here is some sample data:

Table 1 aka Training (T1)

| id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Training 1 |
| 2 | Training 2 |

Table 2 aka Roles (T2)

| id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Role 1 |
| 2 | Role 2 |
| 3 | Role 3 |

Table 3 aka TrainingRoles(T3)

| id | idTraining | IdRoles |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 | 3 |

So far there are 2 tables and a "detail table (t3)"

so what I need to do is get this result:
Result Table

| id | Training Name | Roles |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Training 1 | Role1, Role 2, Role 3, |
| 2 | Training 2 | Role 2, Role 3, |

I tried to do something like this but it gives me separated date even when I use Group By

```
select t1.Name,
(select string_agg(t2.Name, ',')
from   T2 Td2
where  Td2.Id = t3.IdCargo) AS Role
from 
t1 t1
left join T3 t3 on t1.Id = t3.IdTraining
left join T2 t2 on t3.IdRoles = t2.id
group by t1.Name, t3.IdRole
```

I'm using left join so I can get Trainings that don't have a role linked

Comment: Why is `STRING_AGG` in a subquery? Your outer query doesn't have any aggregation either, so why the `GROUP BY`? Seems like you should just be doing the aggregation in the outer query (and the `GROUP BY` should therefore still be there and the subquery shouldn't be).

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I tried this thx to @Larnu and got it solved:

```
select t1.Name,
string_agg(t2.Name, ',') as Role
from
t1 t1
left join T3 t3 on t1.Id = t3.IdTraining
left join T2 t2 on t3.IdRoles = t2.id
group by t1.Name
```